# TYPO3 BE, add TCA button in Backend while editing record

Tags: typo3, backend, typo3-10.x, tca

is there a way to add a kind of a special button to perform some actions while editing a record in BE (TYPO3 10.x.y)? Something like a TCA input field but it should be an "action" button?

The idea is to have this button to perform a query to an external API to prefill/overwrite the records fields' values, while editing a record in BE. So a BE user can decide, if he just wants to edit and save the record or if he wants to query that API first and get the field values prefilled before saving the record.

I tried to do it in the processDatamap_preProcessFieldArray(...) hook but this is not ideal.

Thanks, Alex

Comment: Maybe a custom field-type would be a solution: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/User/Index.html or have a deeper look into the code of the slug-field, which is input-field plus buttons (with actions)